# Can Magento Connect be removed from an installation without side-effect?

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, magento-connect

In our Magento installation we do not use Magento Connect, we add extensions manually and use git for version-controlling our installation and its extensions.  We've blocked all access to Connect via .htaccess, but it would be nice to fully remove it.

Would there be side-effects to removing the entire `downloader/` folder, aside from a broken System menu link (which of course can be removed)?

Comment: Why don't you disable access to Magento connect to all users except the Admin super users?

Comment: we recently had a security breach; it's too early to say that Connect has a vulnerability, but at the moment we believe it was a component of the exploit--so fully removing is preferably to operationally disabling.

Comment: Magento Connect was not the cause of your breach. Dont blame Magento for something you might have missed.

Comment: @mbalparda - oh.  Good.

Answer (score 1):

We have removed the folder downloader in our frondends server and everything work perfect.

My recommendation for you is first to rename the folder to a random name, wait for a 1 week to make sure that nothing else is broken and after that remove the folder.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the input, glad to hear it's been done without issue

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Connect is a part of the core Magento package. Removing or updating core package is considered a Bad Thing, as whatever you do will get undone once you upgrade, potentially with unwanted side-effects.

So no, there's no good way to fully remove Connect, unless you're willing to render your installation upgradability questionable.

Comment: Assuming it can be removed by deleting the `downloader` folder then it can be restored with a single git revert, which is an easy extra step for us to perform during upgrade

Comment: You still have broken links in backend.

Comment: Which is acceptable--my main concern is that the rest of the system continues to function as normal

Comment: Also several command line tools fail after that,  mage script most notably.

Comment: Good to know; that bash script is effectively just a CLI interface to Connect though, right?  So if I were to remove Connect I should remove that as well.